# make a safe password with bottle

Tags: python, sql, hash, passwords, salt

First of all, I am using Python bottle with Sqlite. The trouble that I am having is that when I try to  salt and hash then stop the program. Every page that I have read generates a password in other ways, so that I don't know how to do it. All the ways that I tried were wrong.

```js
def create(self):
  username = request.forms.get('username')
  password = request.forms.get('password')
  email = request.forms.get('email')
  sex = request.forms.get('sex')
  usertype = request.forms.get('usertype')
  registration = datetime.utcnow()
        salt = request.forms.get('password') ########## salt and hash
        hash = hashlib.sha512(password + salt).hexdigest()
  c = self.db.execute('insert into users (username, email, password, registration, sex, usertype) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', \
   (hash, salt, username, email, password, registration, sex, usertype))
```

Answer (score 1):

use "passlib" for password hashing and checking. read its docs and use one of the modern algorithms it suggests, like bcrypt, pbkdf2, sha512_crypt.